# Jquery .find() doesn't return data.....in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery

Jquery Source :

```
       $.ajax({
                type: 'get'
                , dataType: 'text'
                , url: 'navigation.html'
                , cache: false
                , success: function(data, status){
                    var xml;
                    if ($.browser.msie) {
                    xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                    xml.async = false;
                    xml.loadXML(data);
                    } else {
                    xml = data;
                    }

                    $(xml).find('menu').each(function(){    
                        if($(this).attr('level') =="0"){
                ............
```

here navigation.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>       
<navigation id="GNBContainer">
    <menu level="0" nodeId="STS2" parentId="0">
        <name>
            Home
        </name>
        <a href="../index.htm"></a>                     
        </menu>
```

.find() doesn't return data in IE 
but does in FF and chrome
navigation.html, this file extension can not be changed.
navigation.html Content-Type : text/html also can't be changed....
help me.....

Comment: Is the page valid XML (XHTML)?

Comment: what is the contents of `xml`?

Comment: This contents are being used for the top menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't maybe use a workaround, just add an `id` to your element :

```
<menu id="mymenu" level="0" nodeId="STS2" parentId="0">
```

Then you can do :

```
$(xml).find('#mymenu').each(function() {
```

If you can't modify the file, you can eventually do :

```
$(xml).find('#GNBContainer').children().each(function() {
```

But you'll maybe have to adapt this to better comply with your HTML structure.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but $(xml).find('#GNBContainer').children().each(function() { doesn't work